# MSI public properties overriden

Tags: .net, properties, windows-installer, installation

I am creating an MSI and it works quite well when launched manually but the issue arises when I launch it via command line.

I do the command correctly with my properties at the tail of the command, but when I inspect the logs I see the following sequence:

...
MSI (s) (38:18) [04:15:04:283]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASESERVER property. Its value is 'INT-DOM-CONT'.
...
MSI (s) (38:18) [04:15:04:626]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting DATABASESERVER property. Its current value is 'INT-DOM-CONT'.
...

So basically my databaseserver property gets deleted. If I specify a default value in the screen definition in the MSI project, this default value overrides the value passed in the command line.

This behavior starts to make me crazy.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What tool do you use to create your installer?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your installation script to ensure it does not override the property in question. Once I needed to use a condition in the custom action to prevent the property value from being changed and therefore to preserve the value set on the command line.